Analytic and Algebraic Brauer groups of complex symmetric spaces
Let $G$ be a connected reductive group and $K=G^{\sigma}$ where $\sigma$ is an involution of $G$. Could someone please help me to understand what will be the (Analytic) Algebraic Brauer groups of the complex symmetric spaces $G/K$.

Also, please help to understand the third integral cohomology group of symmetric space.
